# How to silent install Postgresql on Windows 7

Tags: c#, postgresql, installation, silent

I want to install "postgresql-9.1.3-1-windows-x64.exe" on windows 7 silently.
Where can i find msi install of postgresql-9.1.3.1

Thank you
Zak

Comment: http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php

Comment: Are you integrating that into another setup? If yes, you can very easily do this by unzipping the zip archives instead of using the installer version

Comment: Were you able to find `.msi` file for postgresql ? This document -http://pginstaller.projects.pgfoundry.org/silent.html clearly explains how to do it but I am not able to find the `msi` installer.

Answer (score 1):

postgresql-9.1.3-1-windows-x64.exe can be downloaded from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/postgresql.mirror/files/postgresql-9.1.3-1-windows-x64.exe/stats/timeline). [This link](http://pginstaller.projects.postgresql.org/silent.html) might help you for silent installation.

Comment: I want to install Postgresql -9.1.3 from my C# application. how can i do?

Answer (score 1):

I've the same problem with PostgreSQL on Windows7 x64, well the solutions that success for me is:

1. Create user postgres and set up password. (User Administrative Tools).
2. Create C:\postgres and set up security full control to user postgres.
3. Execute installer and set C:\postgres as root directory
4. Enjoy it xD

that is all.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
postgresql.exe --mode unattended 
--superpassword youpassword
  --serverport 5432 
       --unattendedmodeui none
      --prefix "c:\postgrespath"
     --datadir "c:\postgrespath\datapath"
```